# Implementing Tiny MCE As Local HTML Editor

Tags: javascript, django, apache, tinymce

UPDATE: There are stupid questions, and this is one of them.  I didn't realize that serving JavaScript via Django was so large a question.  When I've answered it, I'll post the most useful resources for those who want to RTFM, unless the mods close this first.  Until then, sorry for wasting your time.

How do I install and configure Tiny MCE, Apache2 and Django so Tiny MCE is available as a local application only?  I think what I want to do is setup Apache so it serves only the local computer, and does so with Django to provide a Tiny MCE editor.  Apache2 and Django are already installed but I don't know how to integrate Tiny MCE to achieve this result.

I'm a newbie to web development and frameworks, so I might be missing an obvious solution to this problem.

(Why am I doing this?

- I want a WYSIWYG HTML editor that will let me edit a document's formatting and see how that affects the HTML, and edit the HTML and see  how it affects the formatting, while   using a CSS stylesheet.
- I will want to serve this functionality to the web over a  SSL connection but don't yet want to set that up just yet.
- The web application will go through Django, so I want to get  things working through that         framework.
- I'd like to see a JavaScript      application in action.)

Thanks for your patience.

UPDATE: Is this better phrased as:

1. How do I serve a javascript application through Django?
2. How do I make that service available only to the local computer?

Question #2 seems to have been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Bind Apache to the 127.0.0.1 interface only. The documentation can be found at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/bind.html

*What* you serve is irrelvent as far as this question is concerned, since you are just trying to control *where* you serve it too.

Answer (score 0):

In response to q.1 - you don't, normally. Django does not serve static media like JS files, images, etc. Having said that, there is a tinymce app for django which eases the integration. http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/ works well for me.